# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'url' ne peut être vide (null)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am learning Laravel and PHP and I receive this **error** when I submit an empty field :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'url'
>   ne peut être vide (null) (SQL: insert into `urls` (`url`, `shortned`)
>   values (?, 6kuHSS))

I am lost, I don't understand which code make this error...

Here is my code :

```
Route::post('/', function(){
    function make_shortned(){
        $shortned = Str::random(6);
        if(App\Url::whereShortned($shortned)->first())
        {
            return make_shortned();
        }
        else
        {
            return $shortned;
        }
    }

    $data = ['url' => request('url')];
    $validation = Validator::make($data, ['url' => 'required|url']);


    $url = App\Url::where('url', request('url'))->first();

    if($url) // le short existe déjà en bdd
    {
        return view('result')->withShortned($url->shortned);
    }
    else
    {
        $row = App\Url::create([
            'url' => request('url'),
            'shortned' => make_shortned()
        ]);

        if($row) // L'entrée a bien été créée 
        {
            return view('result')->withShortned($row->shortned);
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'test';
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Did you add $fillable in your model?

`protected $fillable = [
     'url',
     'shortned'
];`

Comment: I think yes, here is my Url.php Model : https://pastebin.com/JGrYgDBp

Comment: Is the `url` column nullable?

Comment: can you show dd(request()); ?

Comment: I think not, I read my migration file and I don't see "nullable" anywhere. https://pastebin.com/wuVt4m9a

Comment: Ok I did it by doing :  $table->string('url')->nullable()->change(); then php artisan migrate thank you but now I can see that my validator rules do not work

Comment: I'm not sure making `url` nullable makes sense here. You can't really have a url shortener that allows null urls to be shortened, that doesn't seem useful.

Answer (score 0):

If your `url` field cannot be null then you need to check for that in your validation . You are currently making a validator instance but not actually validating:

```
Route::post('/', function(Request $request){
    function make_shortned() {
        $shortned = Str::random(6);
        if(App\Url::whereShortned($shortned)->first())
        {
            return make_shortned();
        }
        else
        {
            return $shortned;
        }
    }

    $data = $request->validate([
        'url' => 'required|url',
    ]);


    $url = App\Url::where('url', $request->input('url'))->first();

    if($url) 
    {
        return view('result')->withShortned($url->shortned);
    }
    else
    {
        $row = App\Url::create([
            'url' => $request->input('url'),
            'shortned' => make_shortned()
        ]);

        if($row) // L'entrée a bien été créée 
        {
            return view('result')->withShortned($row->shortned);
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'test';
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined variable: request

Comment: Note the `Request $request` in the route function

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your url to nullable update or create a new migration

```
Schema::table('urls', function (Blueprint $table) {$table->string('url', 225)->after('id')->nullable(); });
```